# Mobx does not updating store. need to refresh manually after every action call

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-react

```
import {action, observable, autorun} from 'mobx';

class Streams {
 @observable
 data = null;

 @action
 getStreams() {   
    this.data = ['pen', 'book', 'pencil'];  
 }
}
```

index.js //stores

```
import Streams from './streams';
export default {
 Streams: new Streams(),
};
```

Root.js

```
import stores from './store';
import {inject, observer, Provider} from 'mobx-react';

return(
<Provider {...stores}>
  <Routes>
</Provider>
)
```

Main.js

```
import {inject, observer} from 'mobx-react';
 @inject('Streams')
 @observer
 class Main extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     this.props.Streams.getStreams();
  }

render() {
 console.log(this.props.Streams.data)
 }
```

I am new to mobx. I integrated mobx to my app but store not updating observers at first app launch. need to refresh the app.
For routing i am using 'react-native-router-flux' library.

Comment: Can you provide code in a sandbox?

Comment: can you move getStreams to componentDidMount and see.
Also if possible create a simple codesandbox